# Is it possible to insert a condition in asp-controller attribute of razor form html?

Tags: html, attributes, razor-pages

Is it possible to insert a condition in asp-controller attribute of razor form html?
So if condition is true, the asp-controller=“controller1”,
If false the asp-controller=“controller2”.

I try with

```
<form asp-controller=“@(Model.condition ? Controller1 : Controller2)”
```

But this doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

The controller names should be strings (in quotes):

```
<form asp-controller="@(Model.condition ? "Controller1" : "Controller2")">
```